# Possible to combine generics and reflection in this situation?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I'm trying to call some functionality that requires a type to be passed in a generics situation. I only have a string representation of the type and the assembly that contains the type. **Is this possible somehow?**

The call:

```
var typeName = "CustomNamespace.CustomType";

//CustomNamespace.CustomType should be replaced with typeName
Generator.RegisterTemplate<CustomNamespace.CustomType>();
```

The function:

```
    public void RegisterTemplate<TModel>(string templateName, 
        string templateString)
    {
        templateItems[TranslateKey(typeof(TModel), templateName)] = 
            new RazorTemplateEntry() { 
                ModelType = typeof(TModel), 
                TemplateString = templateString, 
                TemplateName = "Rzr" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") 
            };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx):

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typeAndAssemblyName);
MethodInfo method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("RegisterTemplate");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(...);
```

Using generics with reflection is butt-ugly, but it works.

Comment: `Generator` isn't a static class, it's an instance on which the method needs to be invoked. I'm reading your answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919826/invoke-method-by-methodinfo) and I'm looking at the possibility to make my class static. Is it possible however to do this reflection magic on an instance?

Comment: @Ropstah: This is the first we've heard about the `Generator` class. You can definitely use reflection with an instance, but I'm not sure what the issue is at the moment.

Comment: I was ahead of myself when I commented. `Invoke` takes the object instance as a first parameter so it will work!